# When running a program in Windows, what dictates the allowable memory for that program?

Tags: c, windows

If I were to write a program in C and run it in Windows, is there something in the Win API that dictates whether or not a certain block of memory can be accessed by the program? If I want to be able to have the program access any block of memory that I want, is there something I have to disable? I realize that this is risky and can result in damaging the operating system.

Comment: No just write a driver that runs at ring level 0...and smash the OS, you wish, in your way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Windows (Windows with NT Kernel) the operating systems controls the way memory is accessed. So, the answer is: **NO**. There is nothing you can do about it. You won't be able to get your process to access **ANY** block of memory you want.

You could have done it in Win 3.0, Win 3.11, Win 95, Win 98, Win ME.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible with VirtualAlloc(), the low level function that allocates virtual memory pages.  The flProtect argument specifies how the memory can be accessed by the process, specifying PAGE_NOACCESS is possible, albeit that it is not exactly used very often.

If you are actually talking about *RAM* then no, a user mode program never has direct access to physical memory on a protected mode operating system like Windows.  It can only ever address virtual memory, the mapping to RAM is performed by the OS kernel.  Only code that runs in ring 0 has the capability.  Denying access to certain physical addresses only makes sense for a memory-mapped I/O device.  Which would already have a driver that reserves the address space.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot/will not/must not access kernel memory. Modern operating systems except in kernel mode don't allow to allocate from those memory regions.